# Working on a remote asp.net project from a Mac

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, macos, visual-studio-code

I use a mac, and would like to work on an existing asp.net MVC project that’s running on a Windows Server on our local network. Using VSCode or the new Visual Studio for Mac, is it possible for me to work on that project over the network, either via smb mounted volumes or some other method, while still having the benefits of Intellisense? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: Classic ASP.NET 4.x? You can only edit the source files, but no debugging in either of them. Definitely you get IntelliSense in both, which loads metadata from Mono assemblies I think.

Comment: With Visual Studio for Mac I get the following error 'Error while trying to load the project '/E:folder/anotherFolder/myProject.csproj'' In VS Code I can obviously edit the files but there is no intellisense. The project I'm working on is asp.net 4 but I'd also be curious if it was possible with other versions. Thanks!